# fromJS to nested ordered maps with Immutable.js?

Tags: immutable.js, ordered-map

does anyone have a suggestion for the best way to deep convert a js list of lists to nested ordered maps with Immutable.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fromJS` has a second parameter called [reviver](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS), which can be exactly used for this.

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
const reviver = (key, value) => 
    Immutable.Iterable.isKeyed(value) ? value.toOrderedMap() : value.toList();
const data = Immutable.fromJS(js, reviver);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own [custom conversion](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Converting-from-JS-objects#custom-conversion). For example, to turn JS objects into `Immutable.OrderedMap`:

```
function fromJSOrdered(js) {
  return typeof js !== 'object' || js === null ? js :
    Array.isArray(js) ? 
      Immutable.Seq(js).map(fromJSOrdered).toList() :
      Immutable.Seq(js).map(fromJSOrdered).toOrderedMap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Albert! I think what I was missing was that recursive call to fromJSOrdered on the map

Answer (score 0):

the response by @Albert Olivé had problems on my case use, because of recursion and lack of main context. I've tried with a second context argument to map, with problems again.
Finally I realized that I didn't care about order in submaps, just in main map passed to the function, to maintain order provided by server on html lists. So I changed the function to no recursive this way:

```
 fromJSOrdered(js) {

    if (typeof js !== 'object' || js === null || Array.isArray(js)) { 
      return  fromJS(js);
    }
    return new OrderedMap(fromJS(js));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually published a package recently that can transform an object, array or `Map` of objects into Immutable `List`'s and `Record`'s:

https://github.com/jhukdev/immutable-parsejs

You can take a look at the source if you don't want `Record`'s, easy to change.

`Record`'s are nice though, as you have direct property access, meaning in future if you wanted to switch away from ImmutableJs, it's an easier prospect